# "Permission denied" when installing printer driver on Windows Server 2003 domain workstation

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-server-2003, network-printer

I have a Windows Server 2003 domain running with 30+ workstations. I have a couple of network printers that are on the AD. These are shared (everyone has print permissions).

When I try to install a shared network printer on a workstation in the domain, the installing new drivers prompt pops up and starts to install the driver. All seems to go well until it hits 100%, then it gives me the following message before closing:

> Cannot contact the printer, permission denied.

The printer doesn't get installed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried installing the printer driver with a domain administrator account?

Comment: there are 30+ machines, it's a to much work to install the driver with the admin account on all the machines.. Isn't there a group policy or something?

Comment: Does it work when an Admin-level user installs it?

Comment: Yes, then the driver get installed correctly without problems.

Comment: Yeah, those suck. I'll post an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Contact the printer manufacturer and see if they supply a current, 'universal' driver that supports the model(s) in question.

Remove all other drivers related to the printer on both the servers sharing them, and the clients.

Install the printer using that driver.

Otherwise you're going to have to script an installation of the printer driver under admin. credentials, or visit each machine and install the drivers once.

Vista and 7 are *much* pickier about letting you script printers into place (even in a domain), especially unsigned drivers.

Also, if you mapping the printers via scripts, be aware that if you map them at "startup" (computer policies) instead of "log on" (user policies) then the printer map may not exist wholly in the (standard) users' scope.